# openid ax fetch_request generalize ext1_value and ax_value

Tags: openid

after `fetch_request` google and aol returns `ax` attributes as `openid_ext1_value_*` where as all others return `openid_ax_value_*` How can this be generalized ?

Is it only exception with google ? or can it be anything other than `ax_value` or `ext1_value` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AX spec found here: http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html

You can generalize your solution by looking for the `openid.ns.<extension_alias>=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0` as described in section 1.1 of the spec.

The  value will be the prefix for the rest of the parameters related to that extension.

So in the requests from **Google** and **AOL** you should find `openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0`. Hence all `AX` related requests will be of the form `openid.ext1.<AX parameter>` (e.g. `openid.ext1.mode`).